# Create variables inside switch-case block

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement

I recently run into this problem when writing some code.

I am writing battleship game over LAN, with clients and server sending `Message` class objects.
My switch for reading the message looks like this:

```
    switch (cm.getType()) {
        case Message.HIT:
            String[] partHit = cm.getMessage().split(" ");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(partHit[0]);
            int y = Integer.parseInt(partHit[1]);
            int whoShot = cm.getID();
            if(whoShot == myID){
            display("HIT: " + (char) (x + 64) + y);}
            break;
        case Message.MISS:
            String[] partMiss = cm.getMessage().split(" ");  // ...
            int x2 = Integer.parseInt(partMiss[0]);  // ...
            int y2 = Integer.parseInt(partMiss[1]);  // those are renamed already
            int whoShot = cm.getID();  // this shows error
            if(whoShot == myID){
            display("MISS: " + (char) (x2 + 64) + y2);
            break;
        }

    }
```

What it does, is it extracts shot coordinates and if Im the one who shot it shows that i hit/missed and if it's the other player who shot me, nothing happens (yet).

**My question is:**
Why do I need to rename second `whoShot`, `partHit`, `x` and `y` variables? Shouldn't those be separate, as they are in different code blocks?

I am thinking this: in case the `case : Message.HIT` is never used before `case : Message.MISS`, those variables should not yet be created and should throw an exception when trying to assign value to them. What I am missing here?

Comment: I marked this as duplicate. Feel free to say if it answers your question or not (but I think it should).

Comment: Look up java variable scopes.

Comment: @ZouZou it's a clear duplicate.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel what im asking is why can't I use the same name (as they are separate)?

Comment: @Asalas77 But they are not.

Comment: @ZouZou well JeroenVannevel just said they are :D anyways, the variables are created at the start of `switch` block even if the specific case declaring them is never used?

Comment: Without braces in each case, the scope of the variables is for the whole switch not for the case they are defined. The break statement does not introduce a "scope". Read the answers in the duplicated question. ;)